# java can not read external properties in the same directory with .jar file

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, plugins

I create a jar application, and use maven-shade-plugin to package it.
There are some properties files in it and I use PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to read properties:

```
   <bean id="configurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:/properties/core.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Because I want to update the properties in the file flexible, so I do this to exclude properties when package:

```
        <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>properties/core.properties</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

After package the jar, I create a properties directory contains core.properties and put it in the same directory with jar file.
When I run the jar file:

```
java -jar test.jar
```

It can read the properties in the core.properties files.

But if I create a springboot application and do the same steps but package with spring-boot-maven-plugin.
Then run the jar with the same command:

```
java -jar test.jar
```

An error happened:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:180)
at org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource.getInputStream(EncodedResource.java:159)
at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:99)
at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:73)
at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:59)
at org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePropertySource.<init>(ResourcePropertySource.java:67)
```

Comment: The `properties` directory isn't part of the classpath and hence the `classpath:` prefix will fail.

Comment: @M.Deinum That is what I thought, but it works when use shade plugin to package which confuse me. Now it looks like when use shade plugin, the properies directory is part of classpath, but when use spring boot maven plugin, it is not. But I can not find evidence from somewhere.

Comment: It shouldn't be part of the classpath.